# PHP to create an HTML Table with URLs from a CSV

Tags: php, html, excel, csv, html-table

I'm very new to PHP (and all server side languages) but I'm trying to teach myself.  I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to place on a website as a table.  I was able to pull in a csv through PHP to create the HTML table.  However, I need the last column ("Links") to contain hyperlinks of the word "Go" that once clicked bring you to its respective unique URL.

I would be incredibly grateful for any help.

Here is my PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("market_research.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";

?>
```

For reference, here is a screencap of my table:
[image: html table]

Lastly, here is a screencap of the spreadsheet that I'm using:

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258122/make-a-multi-column-table-from-a-csv-file-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop like this:

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
    echo "<td>";
    if (substr($cell, 0, 4) == "http") { // if the cell starts with http (or https)
        echo "<a href='" . $cell . "'>Go</a>";
    } else {
        echo htmlspecialchars($cell);
    }
    echo "</td>";
}
```